# See only that text which is clicked

Tags: menu, toggle

I do not know why it is not working. I want to see that index paragraph which link paragraph is clicked and do not see others. That's my code:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skrce3a8)

```html
<div class="greyBackground">  
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">1234</a>
                    <a href="#">4567</a>
                    <a href="#">7890</a>
                    <a href="#">0987</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h4>Something</h4>
                <p>My code 1</p>
                <p>My code 2</p>
                <p>My code 3</p>
                <p>My code 4</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {

    var myDiv = $(".greyBackground");
    var link = $(".myDiv").find("a");
    var paragraph = $(".myDiv").find("p");

    link.on("click", function(){

    var index = $(this).index();
        paragraph.hide();
        paragraph.eq(index).show();  

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there is no such class as `myDiv` so your jQuery won't find anything.  You already found the div, though, so you just need to use the variable you created.

```
var myDiv = $(".greyBackground");
var link = myDiv.find("a");
var paragraph = myDiv.find("p");
```

Comment: Also do not forget about `e.preventDefault();`!